# StapleofLife.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: wordpress

Can anyone please check what the problem is with the domain- http://stapleoflife.com/??

Home page is not accessible but subdirectory when typed is loading fine.
Example: http://stapleoflife.com/uncategorized/women-need-use-lot-hormone-substitute-therapyhrt-menopause/

I have not made any major changes except few edits which is usual practice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a site loading issue that cannot be troubleshot simply by visiting the URL.  Further, the solution will have no future value to visitors.

Comment: hi , its an error : 500 with wordpress. i included the link so that it gives the clarity of the error.

Comment: You need to ask your hosting provider.  They can check logs and see what is causing that error.  There is almost zero possibility that we can identify the error just by visiting the site.  Could be an Apache problem, an htaccess problem, php problem.... No way to know with out access to your server logs

Comment: Have you searched 500 error?  That means"internal server error".  My guess is your "edits" to the home page may have introduced a php error

Comment: Thanks cala. Its solved. Indeed it was usual edits issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is solved. 
It was due to bad template.
I see online a lot of googlers searching for this problem.

The problem is either from the recent plugins or theme installation.

Hope it helps for few facing the problem.

P.S : try to Deactive suspected themes or plugins and it shall work.